# ipcRenderer.RemoveListener removes all the listeners of the same class on Electron

Tags: javascript, typescript, electron

On Electron, I make a simple class which assign a listener and remove it after it is called.

```
class Foo {
   void Say(text: string) {
       // The text served to "foo-channel" will be sent back to "foo-channel-reply" after several seconds.
       ipcRenderer.send("foo-channel", text);

       const listener = (e: IpcRendererEvent, text: string) => {
            console.log(text);
            
            // It removes listeners from all the Foo instances!
            ipcRenderer.removeListener("foo-channel-reply", listener);
       };

       ipcRenderer.on("foo-channel-reply", listener);
   } 
}
```

And then, the class behaves as I don't expect.

```
//
// It prints only one message
// while I wanna get all.
//
new Foo().Say("One");
new Foo().Say("Two");
new Foo().Say("Three");
```

It seems that `ipcRenderer.removeListener` removes all the listeners of the same class due to their same IDs.
Please tell me the best way to remove the listener itself.

Comment: The [docs suggest this is appropriate](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrendererremovelistenerchannel-listener), so either you're doing it wrong, or you've found a bug... In the meantime, if you're blocked on this, you might create an entity that sets up a single subscription to the event, and is itself an "event emitter". Then you can take control of the "down-stream" subscriptions rather than relying on the `ipcRenderer` event implementation.